# Splashscreen Rect coordinates returning Screen dimensions on Win 10 Mobile

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I am trying to create an extended SplashScreen on my UWP app for which the SplashScreen image coordinates are needed. I am using the following code in App.xaml.cs:

```
 protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.SplashScreen != null)
                var SplashLocation = e.SplashScreen.ImageLocation;
            //Rest of initialization...
        }
```

However, if I inspect `SplashLocation` which is a `Rect`, `SplashLocation.Height` and `SplashLocation.Width` return 1280 and 768 which is the dimension of my phone's screen. All other properties are 0.

Is this a known bug in Win 10 Mobile [build 10536]? It works fine on desktop Windows 10.

Comment: Does the splash screen cover the entire phone screen?

Comment: No. I just made my splascreen in a different color than the set background color to check that. Splashscreen appears as a centered image.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this, I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Thank god I'm not crazy! Lol.
Yeah I did find a workaround that seems to work almost fine.
I'll post it in a short while.

Comment: Did it work for you @KMan?

Answer (score 2):

Actually the issue is that the code given on the MSDN docs is wrong. Have a look at their samples on Github instead. You can find it here:
[Splash Screen Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SplashScreen)

Notice the differences between the MSDN docs and the sample:

1. ExtendedSplash DOES NOT extend page
2. They use a ScaleFactor for phone
3. The root element of the XAML is Grid and not page.

I followed their sample (after hours of wondering) and it all worked well. I hope they update their docs to reflect the correct thing.

Comment: Good find.

Did you try the MSDN version on latest mobile build? I haven't tried it on a recent build since my workaround still works.

If it still doesn't work then the `ScaleFactor` must be the reason. I don't see how 'not extending from Page' should make a difference.

Comment: I did try it on the latest build and it still doesn't work. Not extending from Page works with adding the ExtendedSpash as a content to the RootFrame, thereby allowing you to control the statusBar color as well

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, here's what I did:

Create an `Image` in XAML inside a `Grid` (and NOT inside a `Canvas` as suggested by the msdn Docs)

```
    <Image Name="ExtSplash" 
           Stretch="Uniform" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Center"  
           VerticalAlignment="Center" 
           Source="Assets/Splash/SplashScreen.png"/>
```

Now, the trick is to make it work on both Mobile (which doesn't give correct `Rect` coordinates and Desktop (which works as expected)

So, in the loaded event of `Page` in code behind, I used this code:

```
    if (splash.Top < splash.Left)
        ExtSplash.Margin = new Thickness(splash.Top);
    else
        ExtSplash.Margin = new Thickness(splash.Left);
```

where `Splash = e.SplashScreen.ImageLocation` from the OnLaunched event in App.xaml.cs.

This works because, `Splash.Top` and `Splash.Left` both return 0 in case of Mobile. So the app just displays the splashscreen fully extended to the width. In case of Desktop, the Image may have some Left or Top Coordinates as it's reported correctly on desktop, where I set them as `Margin` for the centrally aligned uniform stretched image.

NOTE 1: There may be cases where a slight variation may occur between splashscreen and the ExtendedSplash image. But in my testing it worked fine. It will continue to work even when in a later build MS fixes the issue, so you can take your time to implement the standard method then.

NOTE 2: I had some issues with this logic if scale-400 splashscreen image was provided. For some reason WM10 picks up the highest resolution available. So I just supplied 100, 125, 150 and 200 scale images (skipped the 400)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up ditching the `SplashScreen.ImageLocation` approach. The [Microsoft tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187309.aspx) does not work on mobile at the time of writing, and [the sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SplashScreen) is hackish. Instead I used a simple layout like this for the extended splash screen:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Image x:Name="splashScreenImage" Source="Assets/SplashScreen.png" MaxWidth="620" MaxHeight="300"/>
    <!-- plus some other control -->
</Grid>
```

The magic is to use `MaxWidth`/`MaxHeight`.

On mobile the the image will be slightly different positioned vertically (because of status bar and navigation bar I guess), but otherwise correct including size. On desktop the image seems to be exactly positioned and sized as the initial splash.

Comment: can you post your `PositionImage()` ?

Comment: @ravikumar I don't work with this project anymore, sorry.